# How to delete data by name of table in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am still running through the official guidance of Apache IoTDB, and I wonder can IoTDB data be deleted directly by the name of table? If I can delete data by this way, how should I write my sql statement to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete data by the name of table, you can only assigned to time series level of the data structure, and you can also use * to write the sql statement in Apache IoTDB. A usable statement may be: `delete from root.ln.wf02.wt02.*`.